# Why am I getting this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…,

Tags: node.js, json, angular, express, http

I am trying to create a download button, which enables the user to download a document from my node.js server.
Here's the fancy button:
[image]

I am using Angular as a front-end framework and node.js and express.js for the backend.
[image]
For the front-end:

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { GenerateReportService } from "./services/generate-report.service";
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private generateReportService: GenerateReportService) {}
  generateReportbyGet() {
    this.generateReportService.generateReportbyGet().subscribe(() => {
      console.log("generateReportbyGet ...");
    });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button  color="primary" (click)="generateReportbyGet()">Generate report By Get</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**generate-report.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GenerateReportService {
  uri = 'http://localhost:5353';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  generateReportbyGet() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/generateReportByGet`);
  }
}
```

In the backend I have:

**server.js**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');
const createDocumentService = require('./services/generateDocumentService.js');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

router.route('/generateReportByGet').get((req, res) => {
        res.download(path.join(__dirname, 'docs/doc1.txt'), function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log('res.headersSent: ', res.headersSent);
              } else {
                console.log('NO ERROR');
                console.log('res.headersSent: ', res.headersSent);
              }
        });
});

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(5353, () => console.log('Express server running on port 5353'));
```

**doc1.txt**

[image]

When I click on my fancy button, I get this error:

> error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
>   at JSON.parse () at XMLHtt…, text: "This is the text inside
>   doc1.txt that I want the user to be able to download."}
>   headers:
>   HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
>   message: "Http failure during parsing for
>   http://localhost:5353/generateReportByGet" name: "HttpErrorResponse"

I have tested the backend code separately by writing

```
localhost::5353/generateReportByGet
```

in the address bar. And the file gets downloaded successfully.
Also what's strange is that

```
res.download()
```

doesn't give any errors.
So here is my question:
1/ What is causing that error, I get on the browser console?
2/ Is using res.download() the wrong way to do this?
Thank you!!

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data I think that might be the problem. Angular appears to default to expecting to receive JSON data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the response type when you make the request. Angular will otherwise expect the incoming data to be json and try to parse it.

```
 return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/generateReportByGet`, {responseType: 'text'});
```

Comment: Thank you! That did remove the error. However, the file still doesn't get downloaded. I click on the button and nothing haapens? Any idea why? Is there anything wrong with the coding logic I created?  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry - No idea why you can't display data. I guess that should be a separate question.

Comment: No, I don't want to display any data. I just want the user to download the document when he clicks on the button. Just like I explained when I write, localhost:5353/generateReportByGet the document gets downloaded. So the backend works. So I thought if when I implement a logic that sends a GET request when the user clicks on the button to that address should give the same result. At least, could you tell me that my logic is true or false?

Comment: Once you send the GET request, you have the data. If you want the user to download the data, you need to create an anchor and include the data there. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215015/how-can-i-add-a-download-button

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle `res.download` on client side by setting `responseType`.

Modify `GET` request in `generate-report.service.ts` as:

```
generateReportbyGet() {
  return this.http.get(`${this.uri}/generateReportByGet`, {responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
                .map((response: Response)=> response.blob());
}
```

In **app.component.ts** modify `generateReportbyGet` as:

```
generateReportbyGet() {
  this.generateReportService.generateReportbyGet().subscribe((data) => {
    console.log("generateReportbyGet ...");
    // save blob in file
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't see in your answer how you " handle res.download on client side.'. Also, I get this error: Cannot find name 'ResponseContentType'

Comment: @AhmedGhrib `res.download` returns blob. You will have to import `ResponseContentType` from `@angular/http`